# How to check if the string contains only dots and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex to check where a string contains only 3 dots and digits like the following example:

```
let string = 
  "2.3.4.5
   2.3.4.1
   2.3.3.3"
```

where string can contain newline character ?

Comment: deos it have to be a regex?

Comment: not really, but regex would be much "cleaner"

Comment: to clarify, are you wanting to validate this regex against each newline-delimited group of characters in the string?

Comment: @Hamms, i just want to check if the string (that can contain newlines like above) contains only digits and 3 dots

Comment: Are you looking for IP addresses? Are there any limits on the numbers between the dots?

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be what your after.

I've thrown in some invalid one's for good measure.

```js
let str=
`2.3.4.5
2.44.2
2.3.4.1
2.3.3.3
3.4.2.4.5
`;

console.log(
  str.match(/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/gm)
);
```

Comment: thanks @Keith, but match should return false if any of the ip addresses are invalid

Answer (score 1):

This is where the regex `.test()` operation makes sense.

```
/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)+$/gm.test(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some logic you can sample in the direction of utility:

```
let str =
`2.3.4.5
2.44.2

2.3.4.1
234.622.166.2346
1.
127.0.0.1.
125.75.23.110
24.66.256.1
sie4wg4t7hweio478tedehyb5ryb
Thanks\r ok
\n\n
12.34.56.-8
2.3.3.3
3.4.2.4.5
poop
.34.5.34.
`
// beast mode function to check if string is a valid IP between 0-255
const isValidIP = (ip) => {
    if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(ip)) 
        return true
    return false
} 

const results = str
    .split('\n')
    .reduce((all, ip) => {
        const possibleIP = ip.match(/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/gm)
        if (possibleIP && isValidIP(ip)) { all.valid.push(ip) }
        else { all.invalid.push(ip) }
        return all
    }, { valid: [], invalid: [] })

console.log(results)
```

1. split by `\n` to create an array of possible matches
2. run each match through an accumulator, `reduce()`
3. if IP is valid, add it to `results.valid`
4. if IP is anything else, add it to `results.invalid`
5. investigate `results` object

Answer (score -1):

A regex to match valid IPv4 addresses  `0.0.0.0` -- `255.255.255.255`

```
"\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\b"
```

or, if each should occupy all of a single line:

```
"^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$"
```

with setting that `^$` should match at linebreaks.

Comment: I would appreciate it if the downvoter could add a critique.  The OP's question was for a regex for digits and dots; but a subsequent comment by him indicated he was looking for valid IP addresses.